# спарсить рейтинг wta (php)

Tags: php, парсер

```
function curl($url='', $post='', $referer='', $proxy='')
{
    $cl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($cl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($cl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($cl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
    curl_setopt($cl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); 
    curl_setopt($cl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($cl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.1; U; ru) Presto/2.2.15 Version/10.10');
   #curl_setopt($cl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip, deflate'); 
    curl_setopt($cl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
    curl_setopt($cl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
    if(!empty($post)) {
   curl_setopt($cl, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 

   curl_setopt($cl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);}
      else{
      curl_setopt($cl, CURLOPT_POST, 0);}

    if(!empty($referer)){
      curl_setopt($cl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);}
      else{
      curl_setopt($cl,CURLOPT_REFERER, 1);}

    if(!empty($proxy)) {
   curl_setopt($cl, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);}

    $ex=curl_exec($cl);
   #$ex=iconv('cp1251','UTF8',$ex);
    if ($ex === FALSE) {
        echo "cURL Error: " . curl_error($cl);
        curl_close($cl);
    } else {
        curl_close($cl);
            return $ex;
    }
}
echo curl('http://www.wtatennis.com/rankings');
```

пытаюсь получить исходник страницы, но страница скачивается без той таблицы которая мне нужна, как я понял она потом подгружается. как мне эту таблицу получить?

Comment: Отследить с какой страницы качается таблица и качать её. Откройте браузер и посмотрите в инспекторе на закладке сеть, какие запросы идут.

Comment: [Посмотрите тут](http://www.wtatennis.com/node/236341/singles/ranking.json)